# Some ring homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-homomorphism

So I am taking a look at ring homomorphisms, and two examples in the book which are not stated that they are ring homomorphisms, but I think they are not Ring homomorphisms, am I correct?

$\text{i})$ $\phi : \mathbb {C} \rightarrow \mathbb {C}$, given by $\phi(x)=-x$

$\text{ii})$$\phi : \mathbb {C} \rightarrow \mathbb {C}$, given by $\phi(x)=x^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For (i), where does a ring homomorphism have to map $1$? For (ii), is $\phi(x+y) = \phi(x) + \phi(y)$?

Comment: I already know i) cant be a ring homomorphism because for some $a+i$ and $b+i$, $\phi ((a+i)(b+i)) \ne \phi(a+i)\phi(b+i)$ as $ \phi ((a+i)(b+i)) = -(a+i)(b+i) =-\phi(a+i)\phi(b+i).$. And for ii), $\phi(a+i+b+i)=(a+b+2i)^2=(a+b)^2+2(a+i)(b+i)+(b+i)^2 \ne \phi(a+i)+\phi(b+i)$ so it is not a ring homomorphism. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

To be a ring homomorphism (with 1) it has to hold, that

1) $\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)+\phi(y)$

2) $\phi(x\cdot y)=\phi(x)\cdot \phi(y)$

3) $\phi(1)=1$

For your first example it is $\phi(1)=-1\neq 1$. Hence not a ring homomorphism.
For your second example it is $\phi(x+y)=(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2\neq x^2+y^2=\phi(x)+\phi(y)$

Comment: Ok thank you for the clarification. Then how about $\phi : \mathbb {R} \times \mathbb {R}\rightarrow \mathbb {R}$ by $\phi(x,y)=x?$ I think it is a Ring Homomorphism, is this correct?

Comment: Do you mean a ring homomorphism?

Comment: Yes, I meant ring homorphism.

Comment: It is indeed a ring homomorphism. Do you also know why? Or do you struggle with a proof?

Comment: My proof is for some $a+c \in \mathbb{R}$, we have: $\phi((a+c,b))=a+c=\phi(a,b)+\phi(c,b)$. And for $\phi(ac,b)=ac=\phi(a,b)\phi(c,b)$. Is this correct?

Comment: No, this is not correct. But it is going in the right direction. First of all you have to notice, that a ring has two operations "$+$" and "$\cdot$". You have to check both. The second is, that you are just look for a special case, since you just add somethin in the first component. You should do it like this: Let $(x,y), (x',y')\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, then $\phi((x,y)+(x',y'))=\phi((x+x', y+y'))=x+x'=\phi(x,y)+\phi(x',y')$ note that "$+$" (and "$\cdot$") in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ is defined componentwise. Can you check "$\cdot$" yourself?

Comment: Ok I see, I get it now thank you !